# masonry reshuffle after div animation

Tags: jquery-masonry

I'm trying to get the jquery masonry script to reshuffle after I animate the size of a div.  I had seen some examples but I just can't seem to get it working.  I tried:

```
<script>
$(function(){

$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box',
  columnWidth: 100,
  isAnimated: true
});

});
</script>
<script>
$("#test").click( function() {
$("#test").animate ({
"width": 300,
"height": 200
}, 250 );
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box',
  columnWidth: 100,
  isAnimated: true
});
});
</script>
```

I also tried

```
<script>
$(function(){

$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box',
  columnWidth: 100,
  isAnimated: true
});

});
</script>
<script>
$("#test").click( function() {
$("#test").animate ({
"width": 300,
"height": 200
}, 250 );
$("#container|).masonry("reload");
});
</script>
```

For some reason I can't get the reshuffle to happen.  Here is the page it's not working with http://www.klossal.com/masonry.html

thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masonry("reload") should work but you have an error in your line `$("#container|).masonry("reload");`. Your need a closing normal quote and not a pipe like so: `$("#container").masonry("reload");` I also don't think I don't think you need isotope to shuffle. The easist would be to reorder the tiles before feeding it to masonry. Simple look at my site (http://www.phpdevpad.de). When you click on the menu on the left and try different combinations the tiles are shuffled.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the shuffle method, you need to use Isotope; Masonry's bigger sister. See the [github discussion here](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/81).

Comment: I don't think you need isotope to shuffle. The easist would be to reorder the tiles before feeding it to masonry.

Comment: If you want to (re)shuffle, you need to (re)shuffle. Isotope has the shuffle method incorporated. Masonry has no shuffle method incorporate. Simple as that.

Comment: Earth is a flat plane is also simple but it's not true. You don't need to shuffle when you feed the algorithm another order. What's complicated about that. Also isotope isn't free hence not very useful.

Comment: 1. Please try to read questions on SO before trying to answer them. The user asks for reshuffling, hence, she/he should know that reshuffling can be done with Isotope. 2. Isotope only needs to be paid for, if used commercially; see documentation. It is free to use for personal or non-commercial applications. If used commercially, the license fee is minimal. 3. It is generally not liked to promote your commercial web design business by linking to it in your answers.